# Azure App Service: OAuth access and refresh tokens are missing from my request headers after authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication

I am deploying a webapp using Azure App Service which requires authorization to an API (also been deployed as an App Service) on behalf of the user.

According to various tutorials I have followed, after setting up Azure AD authentication, the following tokens should be accessible from the /.auth/me endpoint and passed through as headers on the request:

```
X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN
X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN
X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-EXPIRES-ON
X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-REFRESH-TOKEN
```

However, I am only receiving X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN.

I have added the offline_access scope as required to access refresh tokens on my app, as well as the api://<API_ID>/user_impersonation scope. I have also configured access permissions between the app and API.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this with the same issue, the reason for me was because my IDP did not have access to my client secret; I created my app registration before my app service, rather than at the same time. Therefore the client secret was not stored as the `MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET` application setting, nor applied automatically to the identity provider I added to my app service.

To resolve this I took the following steps:

1. Generated a new client secret from my app registration
2. Copied this into an application setting named `MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET`
3. Went to the authentication panel for my app service, and clicked on the Edit icon on my identity provider
4. Set Client secret setting name to `MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET`

After saving these settings, I can now access the full set of headers.